# Fundamental Group Notation

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, fundamental-groups

I am currently working on a problem in Spanier's *Algebraic Topology* text. Specifically, I'm working on Problem B4 in Chapter 2, which asks one to prove that $\pi(S^1 \vee S^1)$ is nonabelian.

Now, earlier in the text, the author states that $\pi(X,x_0)$ is the fundamental group of $X$ based at $x_0$. Thus, my question is, does the notation $\pi(S^1 \vee S^1)$ here simply denote the fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1$ without a choice of basepoint ? In general, is the notation $\pi(X)$ used often to simply mean the fundamental group of $X$ ? This would make sense to me, since the fundamental group of $X$ is independent of the choice of the basepoint.

Lastly, if $\pi(X)$ really is something different from the fundamental group of $X$, can one accomplish showing that $\pi(X)$ is nonabelian by showing that the fundamental group of $X$ is nonabelian ?

Thank you !

Comment: Spanier is a great book but not very beginner friendly.

Comment: @CarstenS any suggestions for other books besides Hatcher's ?

Comment: I also like Bredon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is common to omit the basepoint when referring to the fundamental group.  This is an abuse of notation, but it is often harmless since, as you mention, the fundamental group of a path-connected space is independent of the choice of basepoint up to isomorphism.  (Though, one should be careful with this, since the isomorphism is non-canonical when the fundamental group is nonabelian!)

I would mention, though, that the notation $\pi(X,x_0)$ (or $\pi(X)$) is *not* commonly used for the fundamental group.  Instead, it is usually called $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ (or $\pi_1(X)$ when the basepoint is suppressed).

Comment: I don't have my copy of Spanier at hand, but I would be surprised if Spanier uses the notation $\pi(X,x_0)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, he does. The fundamental group is introduced in Chapter 1 and higher homotopy groups in Chapter 7, so there is little harm in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a basepoint point, because $S^1\vee S^1$ is path connected.  All the fundamental groups at the different possible base points would be isomorphic.

And $\pi_1(X)$ is usually the fundamental group of $X$, ($\pi_n(X)$ being the $n$-th homotopy group of $X$, where you consider homotopy classes of maps from $S^n$ into $X$.)